# Can any one explain creating arcs using vertices in openGL?

Tags: opengl-es

I am trying to draw circular maze in openGl.For that I created a simple maze in Blender and exported the .obj in to local machine.From the .obj I got the vertices, indices and used them in my code.I am successful in drawing maze with texture.But I am not able to understand how the maze is drawn using those vertices.I see my output,But failed to understand the connections?  Any response would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex: A point in 3D Space.

Index: Which point is used in which order

Three indices creating one Triangle, and this triangle is drawn. Depending on your setting the way the indices are connected is important for you to see the triangle or not. Keywords: CCW, CW and CULL_FACE